# Sometimes MSI exited with code "1073807364"

Tags: windows-installer

I am having a application, which deploy MSI on machine but sometimes this MSI exited with code "1073807364".

After MSI installation machine reboot is required so expected exit code is "1641".

I have look at the different links but i have not able to got concrete answer.

Comment: i get this exit code when my application is closed by Windows due to log off or shutdown.

Comment: This seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078953/in-which-cases-does-program-exit-with-0x40010004-code (1073807364 = 0x40010004).

Answer (score 1):

You should run the installer with logging turned on and read through it for errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this happens when user conditions changes and the SCCM program is expecting special user conditions such as beign logged on. All I do to fix this is create a second advertisement if there are many clients or use the SCCM client center to rerun the adv if only one or wait it out until SCCM retries to install it.