# In which cases does program exit with 0x40010004 code?

Tags: windows, debugging, terminate

My program is designed to run on Windows platform.

Sometimes it terminates with error. I could not debug it on each computer where it is installed; so I added vectored exception handler to it which sends some information about exception to server. There were some `0xC0000005` exceptions; I fixed it, but program still terminates (I could not reproduce error on my PC).

I wrote another program, which waits on main process handle, and sends report with process exit code when main process terminates. I looked at exit codes, and most of them were `0x40010004` (`DBG_TERMINATE_PROCESS`). I know that this exit code appears when debugger is attached to an application and then terminates it; but I am sure that there is no debugger.

So... In which other cases can process be terminated with `DBG_TERMINATE_PROCESS` exit code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On the theoretical side it could be anything, since `TerminateProcess` has an exit code parameter.

On the practical side, it's most likely due to system shutdown. When Windows shuts down, it tries to exit running programs gracefully (more on that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx)). If they refuse to quit, they might be terminated by the system with the exit code `0x40010004`. For example, if you have a GUI program that displays a modal dialog, and then you try to shut down the system, you will be prompted with a message that "xy.exe is preventing shutdown". If you click "Force shutdown", the process will be killed with exit code `0x40010004`.

If you try to reproduce this, be aware that the program waiting on your application's process `HANDLE` might be terminated *before* your main app.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Task Scheduler, set the script to start when the user logs on. If it is set to system startup it will error because it is too early.